# Temporarily disable all currently active jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am making a `TD` element of table editable on double click:

```
$(document).on("dblclick", "#table>tbody>tr>td.cell", function(e) {
    if (e.which != 1 || e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.ctrlKey)
        // need left button without keyboard modifiers
        return;
    reset_selection();
    var editor = document.createElement("div");
    editor.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    editor.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = '';
    // this.style.padding = 0;
    this.appendChild(editor);
    $(document).on("*", stub);
    editor.onblur = function() {
        // this.parentNode.setAttribute("style", "");
        this.parentNode.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        sys.editor = null;
        $(document).off("*", stub);;
    };
    editor.focus();
});

function stub(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}
```

But when i double click on the text inside the editable div, the double click event propagates to the parent td causing undesired consequences. There are also other events (`select`, `mousedown`, etc) i want to prevent, so writing a stub for each of them doesn't look nice to me.

[image]

Is there a way to disable all currently active jQuery event handlers and enable them afterwards? Or somewhow stop propagating all events from the editable div to its parents?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Or somewhow stop propagating all events from the editable div to its parents?

It may not be very palatable, but it's not *that* bad to specifically disable the events:

```
$(this).on("select mousedown mouseup dblclick etc", false);
```

*(Assuming `this` refers to the cell you're editing.)*

There is a limited number of events, after all, and [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) allows you to list them in a space-delimited string and disable them by passing `false`.

You can then re-enable them by passing the same list and `false` again into [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off).

Comment: What if one of `td`'s parents also has some handlers? Do i have also make a stub for each of them?

Comment: @warwaruk: No need, `false` stops propagation.

Comment: I have `<td class="cell cell_selected"><div id="cell_editor" contenteditable="true">#</div></td>`. `this` being the `td`: `$(this).on("selectstart mousedown mouseup dblclick", false);` turns off events not only for `td` but also for its child `div`, so i cannot select text in the div, cannot use double-click to select words, etc

Comment: @warwaruk: It doesn't, but it might seem that way if you're using event delegation, because with delegation you actually hook the element on an ancestor element and rely on it bubbling to that ancestor. If the `td` is between the `td`'s child `div` and the ancestor on which you've hooked the delegated event, since the `td`'s handler stops propagation, the ancestor never sees the event. You can deal with it either by hooking the event on the child directly, or by only *selectively* disabling events by looking at `e.target` in your event handler on the `td` and either letting it through or not.

Answer (score 4):

Use on / off JQuery methods :

```
var myFunction = function(e) {
        if (e.which != 1 || e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.ctrlKey)
            // need left button without keyboard modifiers
            return;
        reset_selection();
        var editor = document.createElement("div");
        editor.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        editor.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = '';
        // this.style.padding = 0;
        this.appendChild(editor);
        $(document).on("*", stub);
        editor.onblur = function() {
            // this.parentNode.setAttribute("style", "");
            this.parentNode.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            sys.editor = null;
            $(document).off("*", stub);;
        };
        editor.focus();
};

function stub(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}

//Active the events
$(document).on("dblclick", "#table>tbody>tr>td.cell", myFunction);

//Disable the events
$(document).off("dblclick", "#table>tbody>tr>td.cell",myFunction);

//Reactive the events
$(document).on("dblclick", "#table>tbody>tr>td.cell", myFunction);
```

**Update**

You can also manage a variable set to `true` if the event must not be taking into account :

```
var skipEvent = true;

$(document).on("dblclick", "#table>tbody>tr>td.cell", function (e) {
    //Check variable and skip if true
    if (skipEvent) 
        return false;

    if (e.which != 1 || e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.ctrlKey)
    // need left button without keyboard modifiers
    return;
    reset_selection();
    var editor = document.createElement("div");
    editor.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    editor.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = '';
    // this.style.padding = 0;
    this.appendChild(editor);
    $(document).on("*", stub);
    editor.onblur = function () {
        // this.parentNode.setAttribute("style", "");
        this.parentNode.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        sys.editor = null;
        $(document).off("*", stub);;
    };
    editor.focus();
});
```

Comment: I wrote in the question: "There are also other events (select, mousedown, etc) i want to prevent, so writing a stub for each of them doesn't look nice to me."

Comment: You can also manage a variable set to true if the event must not be taking into account, check my last update