# JQuery event listener execute first

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is the following:

I have an external library that has an event listener over a certain div (.MagicThumb-swap) and when the user clicks it the library does some work.

I have to add an event listener that has to execute BEFORE the one of the library.

This is the code of the event listener that I want to run first:

```
$(".MagicThumb-swap").on("click", function () {
    $("#Zoomer2").show();
    $("#videoShow").remove();
});
```

The question is: How do I make my event listener execute before the other one? I'm not allowed to modify the library so modifying the other event is out of question.

EDIT:

I have my code like this:

```
 <script>
    $(document).on("click", ".MagicThumb-swap > img", function () {
        console.log("clicked");
        $("#Zoomer2").show();
        $("#videoShow").remove();
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".videoShowMini", function () {
        $("#videoShow").remove();
        $("#Zoomer2").hide();
        $("#zoomerContainer").prepend("<div id='videoShow'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>");

    });
</script>
<script src="../magiczoomplus/magiczoomplus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and it's still not executing first.

Comment: whatever your code is put before all other code lines.

Comment: Include the script before including external JS file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849544/temporarily-disable-all-currently-active-jquery-event-handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your event registering code before calling your library's function that will set their own handler, your handler will be called first.

For example, if you were using a jQuery slider plugin

```
// Call your event registering code 
$( ".selector" ).click(function(){ console.log('My event handler')});
// Now initialize the external lib
$( ".selector" ).slider({ animate: "fast" });
```

Note that if you use event delegation, your event handler will be called after an event that was set directly on the element (because it has to wait until the event bubbles up the tree).

I think the only way to get around this problem is not using event delegation.

```
$(".MagicThumb-swap > img").click(function () {
    console.log("clicked");
    $("#Zoomer2").show();
    $("#videoShow").remove();
});

$(".videoShowMini").click( function () {
    $("#videoShow").remove();
    $("#Zoomer2").hide();
    $("#zoomerContainer").prepend("<div id='videoShow'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>");
});
```

Also note that if you don't want their handler to be called at all, you'll have to call http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

This means that if you're inserting the `.MagicThumb-swap > img` element dynamically, you'll have to register the handler it when adding the element to the DOM (so it works) and removing the handler when removing the element from the DOM (to prevent memory leaks)

Answer (score 0):

By how I read it, it seems like this magical external library automatically listens to the `.MagicThumb-swap` element and when clicking the element you want your code to fire then their code.

This is how I would go about doing it:

```
$(".MagicThumb-swap-handler").on("click", function () {
    $("#Zoomer2").show();
    $("#videoShow").remove();
    $(".MagicThumb-swap").click();
});
```

So basically, create another new element which acts as the handler for the actual action you want. When the element `.MagicThumb-swap-handler` is clicked, it does its thing and then once it's done, fires off the `click` event for `.MagicThumb-swap`.

Comment: It still doesn't enter and if I force the event with $(".MagicThumb-swap-handler").click() it does and infinite loop.

Comment: The loop is created by the issues with bubbling - the magicthumb-swap click event bubbles up to the handler one (assuming it's a wrapper). You would need to use `function(e)` and check the `e` event object for the target etc